# Private bucket and expiring URLs

Tags: php, amazon-s3

I've been looking through the documentation and googled but just can't figure it out.

How can I set my S3 bucket to be private (ie, only my PHP application can access the files and no-one lese) and generate expiring URLs when I want to give access to a specific file for a specific person?

I am able to generate authenticated URLs but the address to the file is visible in this address and when I access the file from a web browser without the access key and the signature, the file is still downloadable!

The authenticated URL:
http://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com/myfile.jpg?AWSAccessKeyId=thekey&Expires=1378302758&Signature=signaturestring

If I now take just the address to the file:
http://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com/myfile.jpg,
it's still downloadable. I need to prevent that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you don't have a bucket policy attached to that bucket that gives everyone permissions to read your files.

Also check the ACLs for each file and remove any `public-read` permissions.

Check the S3 docs for more info:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ACLOverview.html
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingResOpsConditions.html